# Cached data returned when making same Web API call consecutively using Breeze.js

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze, single-page-application, durandal-2.0

I am facing a strange issue while writing a Breeze.js with Durandal SPA (largely based on John Papa's Great SPA Jumpstart (https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal) training ), the issue when a try to make the same server API call multiple times consecutively the server is hit only once and one the second call it seems I get cached data (call doesn't even hit server), this can be replicated in Jumpstart sample too, below is the modified code to replicate this on Jumpstart

```
 var activate = function () {
            for (var i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++) {

                 datacontext.getSessionPartials(sessions, true);
            }
        };



var activate = function () {

        for (var i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
        {
            datacontext.getSpeakerPartials(speakers, true);
        }
    };
```

Edit- Updated with the complete code  :

Code of my Viewmodel

```
define(['services/datacontext'], function (datacontext) {
    var speakers = ko.observableArray();

    var activate = function () {

        for (var i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
        {
            datacontext.getSpeakerPartials(speakers, true);
        }
    };
    var refresh = function () {
        return datacontext.getSpeakerPartials(speakers, true);
    };

    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        speakers: speakers,
        title: 'Speakers',
        refresh: refresh
    };

    return vm;
});
```

Below is code of my datacontext/service :

```
define([
    'durandal/system',
    'services/model',
    'config',
    'services/logger',
    'services/breeze.partial-entities'],
    function (system, model, config, logger, partialMapper) {
        var EntityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery;
        var manager = configureBreezeManager();
        var orderBy = model.orderBy;
        var entityNames = model.entityNames;

        var getSpeakerPartials = function (speakersObservable, forceRemote) {

            if (!forceRemote) {                
                var p = getLocal('Persons', orderBy.speaker);
                if (p.length > 0) {
                    speakersObservable(p);
                    return Q.resolve();
                }
            }

            var query = EntityQuery.from('Speakers')
                .select('id, firstName, lastName, imageSource')
                .orderBy(orderBy.speaker);

            return manager.executeQuery(query)
                .then(querySucceeded)
                .fail(queryFailed);

            function querySucceeded(data) {
                var list = partialMapper.mapDtosToEntities(
                    manager, data.results, entityNames.speaker, 'id');
                if (speakersObservable) {
                    speakersObservable(list);
                }
                log('Retrieved [Speaker] from remote data source',
                    data, true);
            }
        };

        var getSessionPartials = function (sessionsObservable, forceRemote) {
            if (!forceRemote) {
                var s = getLocal('Sessions', orderBy.session);
                if (s.length > 3) {
                    // Edge case
                    // We need this check because we may have 1 entity already.
                    // If we start on a specific person, this may happen. So we check for > 2, really
                    sessionsObservable(s);
                    return Q.resolve();
                }
            }

            var query = EntityQuery.from('Sessions')
                .select('id, title, code, speakerId, trackId, timeSlotId, roomId, level, tags')
                .orderBy('timeSlotId, level, speaker.firstName');

            return manager.executeQuery(query)
                .then(querySucceeded)
                .fail(queryFailed);

            function querySucceeded(data) {
                var list = partialMapper.mapDtosToEntities(
                    manager, data.results, entityNames.session, 'id');
                if (sessionsObservable) {
                    sessionsObservable(list);
                }
                log('Retrieved [Sessions] from remote data source',
                    data, true);
            }
        };

        var getSessionById = function(sessionId, sessionObservable) {
            // 1st - fetchEntityByKey will look in local cache 
            // first (because 3rd parm is true) 
            // if not there then it will go remote
            return manager.fetchEntityByKey(
                entityNames.session, sessionId, true)
                .then(fetchSucceeded)
                .fail(queryFailed);

            // 2nd - Refresh the entity from remote store (if needed)
            function fetchSucceeded(data) {
                var s = data.entity;
                return s.isPartial() ? refreshSession(s) : sessionObservable(s);
            }

            function refreshSession(session) {
                return EntityQuery.fromEntities(session)
                    .using(manager).execute()
                    .then(querySucceeded)
                    .fail(queryFailed);
            }

            function querySucceeded(data) {
                var s = data.results[0];
                s.isPartial(false);
                log('Retrieved [Session] from remote data source', s, true);
                return sessionObservable(s);
            }

        };

        var cancelChanges = function() {
            manager.rejectChanges();
            log('Canceled changes', null, true);
        };

        var saveChanges = function() {
            return manager.saveChanges()
                .then(saveSucceeded)
                .fail(saveFailed);

            function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
                log('Saved data successfully', saveResult, true);
            }

            function saveFailed(error) {
                var msg = 'Save failed: ' + getErrorMessages(error);
                logError(msg, error);
                error.message = msg;
                throw error;
            }
        };

        var primeData = function () {
            var promise = Q.all([
                getLookups(),
                getSpeakerPartials(null, true)])
                .then(applyValidators);

            return promise.then(success);

            function success() {
                datacontext.lookups = {
                    rooms: getLocal('Rooms', 'name', true),
                    tracks: getLocal('Tracks', 'name', true),
                    timeslots: getLocal('TimeSlots', 'start', true),
                    speakers: getLocal('Persons', orderBy.speaker, true)
                };
                log('Primed data', datacontext.lookups);
            }

            function applyValidators() {
                model.applySessionValidators(manager.metadataStore);
            }

        };

        var createSession = function() {
            return manager.createEntity(entityNames.session);
        };

        var hasChanges = ko.observable(false);

        manager.hasChangesChanged.subscribe(function(eventArgs) {
            hasChanges(eventArgs.hasChanges);
        });

        var datacontext = {
            createSession: createSession,
            getSessionPartials: getSessionPartials,
            getSpeakerPartials: getSpeakerPartials,
            hasChanges: hasChanges,
            getSessionById: getSessionById,
            primeData: primeData,
            cancelChanges: cancelChanges,
            saveChanges: saveChanges
        };

        return datacontext;

        //#region Internal methods        

        function getLocal(resource, ordering, includeNullos) {
            var query = EntityQuery.from(resource)
                .orderBy(ordering);
            if (!includeNullos) {
                query = query.where('id', '!=', 0);
            }
            return manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
        }

        function getErrorMessages(error) {
            var msg = error.message;
            if (msg.match(/validation error/i)) {
                return getValidationMessages(error);
            }
            return msg;
        }

        function getValidationMessages(error) {
            try {
                //foreach entity with a validation error
                return error.entitiesWithErrors.map(function(entity) {
                    // get each validation error
                    return entity.entityAspect.getValidationErrors().map(function(valError) {
                        // return the error message from the validation
                        return valError.errorMessage;
                    }).join('; <br/>');
                }).join('; <br/>');
            }
            catch (e) { }
            return 'validation error';
        }

        function queryFailed(error) {
            var msg = 'Error retreiving data. ' + error.message;
            logError(msg, error);
            throw error;
        }

        function configureBreezeManager() {
            breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
            var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager(config.remoteServiceName);
            model.configureMetadataStore(mgr.metadataStore);
            return mgr;
        }

        function getLookups() {
            return EntityQuery.from('Lookups')
                .using(manager).execute()
                .then(processLookups)
                .fail(queryFailed);
        }

        function processLookups() {
            model.createNullos(manager);
        }


        function log(msg, data, showToast) {
            logger.log(msg, data, system.getModuleId(datacontext), showToast);
        }

        function logError(msg, error) {
            logger.logError(msg, error, system.getModuleId(datacontext), true);
        }
        //#endregion
});
```

Below is the code for BreezeController/WebApi

```
namespace CodeCamper.Controllers
{
    [BreezeController]
    public class BreezeController : ApiController
    {
        readonly EFContextProvider<CodeCamperDbContext>  _contextProvider =
            new EFContextProvider<CodeCamperDbContext>();

        [HttpGet]
        public string Metadata()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Metadata();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
        {
            return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public object Lookups()
        {
            var rooms =  _contextProvider.Context.Rooms;
            var tracks =  _contextProvider.Context.Tracks;
            var timeslots =  _contextProvider.Context.TimeSlots;
            return new {rooms, tracks, timeslots};
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Session> Sessions()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.Sessions;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Person> Persons()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.Persons;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Person> Speakers()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.Persons
                .Where(p => p.SpeakerSessions.Any());
        }

   }
}
```

Please help/advise.

Comment: This doesn't show any logic related to Breeze nor Web API.  The issue is you are probably telling it to query locally within your Breeze query but without seeing it no one will be able to help!

Comment: I have updated the question with code, I rechecked the code tries to get the data from the server not locally.